# socketIO clients do not receive message from server

Tags: python, sockets, flask, flask-socketio

I have a simple flask/socketIO app as follows:

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/work')
def work():
    print('in work')
    socketio.emit('work', broadcast=True)
    print('after emit')
    return 'ok'

@socketio.on('report')
def save_report(data):
    print('in report...')
    with open('f_', 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

**client.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
import sys

socketio = SocketIO('127.0.0.1', 5000 )
app = Flask(__name__)

def handle_work():
    print('slave - work')
    socketio.emit('report', {'data': 123})

@app.route('/details')
def details():
    return {'details': 'during work'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = int(sys.argv[1])
    socketio.on('work', handle_work)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000+k, debug=True)
```

I execute the server.py and 3 client.py with arguments 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

and then executes curl localhost:5000/work

I was hoping to execute the code in handle_work() on my clients, but they do not receive the event emitted from the server.

Can anyone help me to see what the problem is?

Comment: It seems that you have to render a HTML file in your server. Like in `@app.route('/work')`, you have to `return render_template('yourhtml.html')`

Comment: Also, on your client-side. I suggest you learn a little bit of javascript for handling the client-side connection with the server. It will be easy to follow the template of socket.io: [link](https://socket.io/)

Comment: Hi @Oscar916, thanks for the suggestions, but I think the problem is in the client side, the server side endpoint /work does works apparently well, and write 'ok' in the browser, so, there is no need of a template html. I also prefer the app to be in completely in python.

Comment: The Socket.IO client that you are using is not asynchronous I believe, when you want to wait for messages from the server you have to call a waiting function. Check their docs to see some examples of how they do it.